# How to merge rows in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, dataframe

I am trying to understand how to merge two rows (which are the same) into one. They both have data that needs to be in the same row but the raw data currently has split them into two rows. Essentially, I need AML business 1 to be on one row with values for 2019:W26 - 2019:W29. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: If you want to merge two rows, there are not the same. So you have to group them by what they have in common. Please provide SQL query so we can point you to that.

Comment: As I am quite new to this, what would you require within an SQL query? The tables?

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All answer above ar correct, try this one:

```
SELECT
        Team,
        MAX(2019-W26) AS 2019-W26,
        MAX(2019-W26) AS 2019-W27,
        MAX(2019-W26) AS 2019-W28,
        MAX(2019-W26) AS 2019-W29
    FROM
        table_name
    GROUP BY
    Team;
```

Comment: @inadel . . . You need to delimit those column names to avoid compiler errors.

Comment: aren't you missing `country` here?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to have all your information is one row, you can create a view combining both of your two rows into one.